# Export file problem in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, error, export, importexport, file-upload

[image]

> Error: "Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon"

enter code here Open `admin panel/system/Data Transfer/Export`

After that select all export setting and click the continue button.

When clicking on the continue button above the error show.

**Why files are not export? How to export files?**

Please suggest.

Thank you so much.

Comment: please execute php bin/magento cron:run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace this below code in `app/code/Magento/ImportExport/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/Export.php` File

---

This code is working in my application

```
public function execute()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost(ExportModel::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP)) {
        try {
            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export::class);
            $model->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());
            $this->sessionManager->writeClose();

            return $this->fileFactory->create(
                $model->getFileName(),
                $model->export(),
                \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                $model->getContentType()
            );

            /** @var ExportInfoFactory $dataObject */
            $dataObject = $this->exportInfoFactory->create(
                $params['file_format'],
                $params['entity'],
                $params['export_filter']
            );

            $this->messagePublisher->publish('import_export.export', $dataObject);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon')
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
    }
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $resultRedirect->setPath('adminhtml/*/index');
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

Comment: Hello ., I have try with this code, File get exported but only some column are showing  and no data  exported

Answer (score 25):

If your var/importexportxxx file is blank try;

`php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor`

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23450

Comment: I can confirm this works as a temporary fix as Battamich's answers is my solution. (it's actually me!)

Comment: use & in the end of the command to make it run in background
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor &

Answer (score 12):

You have to run cron by command line as mentioned here: `php bin/magento cron:run`

> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23450#issuecomment-507581035

Then refresh the export page and you should see the file at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm using magento 2.3.2 cloud locally and this solution doesn't work for me.. I see that some files are generated inside var folder as "importexport_{id_number}" but they are all empty!

Comment: How to make it work on localhost xampp

Comment: Thanks a lot, superb!!!

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to what [Andrew Taylor](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/39457/andrew-taylor) said, you can add the `exportProcessor` consumer (and others) to cron by adding the following to your `app/etc/env.php` file:

```php
    'cron_consumers_runner' => [
        'cron_run' => true,
        'max_messages' => 20000,
        'consumers' => [
            'async.operations.all',
            'codegeneratorProcessor',
            'exportProcessor',
            'product_action_attribute.update',
            'product_action_attribute.website.update'
        ]
    ],
```