# Magento 2.3.2 Product Export Message: "Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon"

Tags: product, export, magento2.3.2

when i have product export and below message showing

> Error: "Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon"

Also i run cron command like

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

still not downloading CSV file

i know here [asking](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/284794/68695) someone but this is not working for me 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to fix Following way..

Open below file

> vendor/magento/module-import-export/Controller/Adminhtml/Export/Export.php

and replace below function

```
public function execute()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost(ExportModel::FILTER_ELEMENT_GROUP)) {
        try {
            $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
            $model = $this->_objectManager->create(\Magento\ImportExport\Model\Export::class);
            $model->setData($this->getRequest()->getParams());
            $this->sessionManager->writeClose();

            return $this->fileFactory->create(
                $model->getFileName(),
                $model->export(),
                \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                $model->getContentType()
            );

            /** @var ExportInfoFactory $dataObject */
            $dataObject = $this->exportInfoFactory->create(
                $params['file_format'],
                $params['entity'],
                $params['export_filter']
            );

            $this->messagePublisher->publish('import_export.export', $dataObject);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                __('Message is added to queue, wait to get your file soon')
            );
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->critical($e);
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please correct the data sent value.'));
    }
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $resultRedirect->setPath('adminhtml/*/index');
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

**Please don't forget to clear cache after change in files**

Comment: This solution indeed allow to download the file directly; I've been using it a lot as a workaround; but...kinda would like to suceed fixing the cron job itself. Can't understand why the message_queue is there but nothing happen after even running cron manually this is the real issue.

Answer (score 24):

Run this command then check in admin

> php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor

you will get download option

[image]

Comment: yes downloading  but it taken too much time not quickly downloading

Answer (score 0):

After cron command just refresh the page if still you don't get the file check the notification icon
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried changed the code in the export.php file and it works. The pending issue is that the files available to download are not seen at another time. Is it possible to fix that error?

Comment: If you have follow on questions, please ask a new question rather than posting it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the the Add Secret Key to URL option

- In the Magento Admin, navigate to Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security.
- Set the Add Secret Key to URLs option to No.
- Click Save Config.
- Clean cache under System > Tools > Cache Management or by running bin/magento cache:clean or in Magento Admin.

To get the exported file, run the bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor command. After running this, the file should be displayed in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Just run this command in magento2 directory
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
If you have root privileges otherwise you put sudo before command like this
sudo php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor